# How to guarantee an API user that a promise never rejects

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a promise returning function and that promise never rejects I always handle all errors and still resolve a value. I want to inform the user that s/he doesn't have to append catch function to the promise.

```
const createItem = (name: string): Promise<boolean> => {
   return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
       someAjaxCall().then(response => {
           if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
              resolve(true);
           } else {
              handleError();    // some logging to console
              resolve(false);
           }
       }).catch(error => {
           handleError();    // some logging to console
           resolve(false);
       });
   });
}
```

Actually changing return type to `Promise<void>` and replacing `resolve(true)` parts with `resolve()` and replacing `resolve(false)` parts with `reject()` solves my problem.

But I want to know that is there any other elegant way to tell the API user that "you won't ever need to append catch and you must handle exactly these values in your then".

Comment: It's an interesting question, but the answer to it almost certainly shouldn't be applied to the above. The error should propagate to the caller, like this: https://pastebin.com/pN83qeED Don't convert the failure to a fulfillment with the value `false` rather than `true`. The calling code will have to take two different branches anyway, so let failures be errors.

Comment: Catching and handling errors is an application level thing. Low level utilities may have intermediate (mid-chain) catches for whatever reason but no terminal catch; that belongs in the caller or caller's caller or higher.

Comment: But .... if it's a high level utility, then possibly yes. It's a design decision.

Comment: Actually, API user is also me here :) I'm designing a module and this method belongs to some utli class. I'm calling this method in some higher level class in the same module and I can leave catch parts empty. But, I basically don't want that after some time somebody comes and says oh why these promises' error cases aren't handled. I want to make it obvious that these promises don't need any catch parts. But, promises are not meant for this i guess. I need to write some comment or something for this method to make it understandable..

Comment: @M.Yilmaz, if you don't intend to handle the exceptions, then don't add catch clauses.

Comment: Also you really need to avoid `new Promise()` for cases like this. It's completely unneeded. Just `return someAjaxCall().then( ... etc.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to know that is there any other elegant way to tell the API user that "you won't ever need to append catch and you must handle exactly these values in your then".

No. Similar to the fact that there is no way in the type system to say a *function never throws* there is no way for *promise never rejects*.

Your only option is to add documentation for this fact if you want